# How to factor $f=x^2+10xy+y^2$ into a difference of squares?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been looking at this problem for a while, and can't really figure out how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out: $f=(x+5y)^2-24y^2$

Comment: As for if it goes like that then there is also another way $$(5x+y)^2-(2\sqrt 6x)^2$$

Comment: @Manthanein Or even $\,(x+y)^2 \,-\, \left(i \,2\sqrt{2xy}\right)^2\,$. I think the OP left out too much of what they really meant to ask.

Comment: @dxiv Yep you are absolutely correct